# How to create a canvas box hover effect using HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: html, css, canvas

I am trying to develop a canvas box hover effect using HTML5 & CSS3, but I cannot get this to work. I would like to make an effect like seen below:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QkiZ.jpg when the user is not hovering
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zRWi.jpg when user is hovering

i.e. how can I make a blue triangle and turn it into a blue square when the user hovers over it using HTML5 canvas?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Here we help solve problems with existing code rather than creating code when no code already exists. Canvas can fill your need, but would require some javascript to make it happen. Instead, perhaps you can create the same hover effect using CSS and 2 different images.

Comment: i dont know how to create using graphicaly repratation using css on below images  http://i.stack.imgur.com/7QkiZ.jpg  ablove images would be create using css  http://i.stack.imgur.com/4zRWi.jpg

Comment: Here's an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/pug372er/) that changes your images when hovering.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/7g7tyn2c/

### Notes:

- We can draw on  the canvas once we get its context using `document.getElementById("canvasid").getContext("2d");` We reference this context (which we store in a variable `ctx`) whenever we want to draw, as all the drawing functions are stored there.
- We also know that we're only going to be drawing in blue, so we set the fill colour `ctx.fillStyle="blue"` before we do anything else. If you wanted a different colour, you *can* use HEX codes like so: `ctx.fillStyle="#0000ff";`
- Two different functions: One that draws a blue triangle (this is the normal state), and one that draws a blue rectangle (hover state). These are called by the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events on the canvas element. The normal function is also called on page load.
- In the normal state, we first tell the canvas to start at the bottom-right hand corner by using `ctx.moveTo(0,0,256,256);`
- We can then draw paths using `ctx.lineTo(x,y)` from the current position. This is like the [vector pen tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/pen-tool-game.html) in Illustrator
- To make the whole thing blue on hover (for the hover function), we draw a blue rectangle covering the whole area using `ctx.rect(0,0,256,256)`.
- If we didn't remove this `onmouseout`, then we would be drawing a blue triangle on top of the square and it would remain all blue. To avoid this, we using `ctx.clearRect(0,0,256,256)` to get rid of all canvas content and start again. This is run in the normal function.

Comment: yes its file , also inside line how can draw like as show my above images

Comment: yes its perfect but you do same canvas opposit way like.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/jEhK1.jpg to http://i.stack.imgur.com/XMdUA.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Really? Just use the `:hover` selector.

```
canvas:hover {
```

```css
canvas:hover {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="my-canvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
```